# Do UK Visa Application Forms expire?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm applying for an Exemption Vignette Visa for the UK from Italy. I made a mistake and I need to start over. I'd like to cancel the current application (I still have to bring the requested documents to the application center) but in order to do so I need to send a cancellation request and I have to pay for it.

Unfortunately, my cards are not accepted. My question is: is the visa application going to expire anyway? Or should I really cancel it? On the website it is written that the application form is available to download until February 2020, so I assume they cancel these incomplete applications anyway.

Comment: What sort of mistake did you make? You may be able to point it out and have something altered instead of cancelling it completely

Comment: @Uciebila I believe I would still have to contact them and thus have to pay for it! It’s strange that they don’t simply automatically delete old applications, though.

Answer (score 1):

## If you have submitted your application

If you have submitted your application you should pay tour fee which can later be refunded.

2 ongoing visa applications won’t be allowed.

The [UK GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa) states:

> [Contact UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) to find out how to cancel your application.
>
> You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been processed yet.

## If you haven’t submitted your application

If your application hasn’t been submitted you can just start again and if asked just say you made a mistake.

Comment: I did not pay anything as this type of Visa is free of charge. Nonetheless, I submitted it to the point that I now have to take an appointment with the commercial partner in my home country to submit the requested documents. The problem is that I don't really know how to pay for the request to cancel the current application.

Comment: @wrong_path I think you can just leave it, make a new application and if asked say you made a mistake